# Dynamically change carousel images based on click event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 elements arranged in a row. I want to show a carousel pop-up on click of the columns in the row. The issue is I am not able to change the images of carousal based on selected column element.

Here is my complete code:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
      <style>
      .carousel-inner > .item > img,
      .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        width: 70%;
        margin: auto;
      }
      </style>
    </head>
    <script>
    function process() {
     var shops = JSON.parse('{ "id": "shopping", "categories": [ { "id": "Amazon", "name": "Amazon", "link": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/SellerCentral/legal/amazon-logo_transparent._CB303899249_.png", "images": [ { "href": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/credit/img16/CBCC/marketing/marketingpage/products._V524365396_.png" }, { "href": "http://static4.uk.businessinsider.com/image/575adbe2dd0895c4098b46ba/the-50-most-popular-products-on-amazon.jpg" } ] }, { "id": "Google", "name": "Google", "link": "http://pngimg.com/uploads/google/google_PNG19644.png", "images": [ { "href": "https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/147-1476512_google-google-products-logos-png.png" }, { "href": "https://xvp.akamaized.net/assets/illustrations/unblock-google/unblock-google-with-a-vpn-fc1e32f59d9c50bae315c2c8506a91e2.png" } ] }, { "id": "Apple", "name": "Apple", "link": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Apple_Logo.svg/2000px-Apple_Logo.svg.png", "images": [ { "href": "https://c.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/apple-mfi-logos-update-2018-980x620.jpg" }, { "href": "https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/applemusic/itunes-apple-logo-apple-music-giftcard.jpg" } ] } ] }');
     var row = 1;
     var content = "";
     shops = shops.categories;
     for(var i=0; i< shops.length; i++) {
      if(row == 1) {
       content += '<div class="row">'
      }
      content += '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12" data-toggle="modal" onclick="processCarousel(shops[i])" data-target="#myModal">';
      content += '<img style="border: 1px solid red" src="'+shops[i].link+'" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>';
      if(row == 3) {
       row = 0;
       content += '</div>';
      } 
      row++;
     }
     document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = content;
     processCarousel(); 
    }
    
    function processCarousel(input) {
     alert(input);
     var m = ['img_chania.jpg','img_chania2.jpg', 'img_flower.jpg','img_flower2.jpg'];
     var carouselInner = document.getElementById("carousel-inner");
     var carouselIndicators = document.getElementById("carousel-indicators");
     var innerContent = "";
     var indicatorsContent = "";
     for(var i=0 ; i< m.length ; i++) {
      var c = "";
      if(i == 0) {
       c = " active";
      }
      innerContent += '<div class="item'+c+'"><img src="'+m[i]+'"><div class="carousel-caption"></div>   </div>';
      indicatorsContent += '<li class='+c+'data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="'+i+'"></li>';
     }
     carouselInner.innerHTML = innerContent;
     carouselIndicators.innerHTML = indicatorsContent;
     var carouselExampleGeneric = document.getElementById("carousel-example-generic");
     carouselExampleGeneric.carousel();
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

The above code generates the below output:

[image]

On click of any image it is loading the carousal but the images of carousal are fixed to my array elements `var m = ['img_chania.jpg','img_chania2.jpg', 'img_flower.jpg','img_flower2.jpg'];` as mentioned in my above code.

But I want to show only the selected images which are present in my input json `shops.categories[selectedItem].images`

I tried using `onclick` javascript event on column element, but the code is not recognising it. What is the correct way to do this.

I want to do this using plain javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get rid of the call to `processCarousel();` in line 39.

Your main problem is, that inside of your content variable you are passing the string of the argument variable rather than the argument itself. Try this instead:

```
content += '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12" data-toggle="modal" onclick="processCarousel(' + i + ')" data-target="#myModal">';
```

This way you are just passing the index of the category that needs to be rendered.
Then you will have to have the shops object available inside of the processCarousel function as well, so I moved it up, outside the function scope.

This will result in further problems inside of you processCarousel function. You will have to set your your images like this `var m = shops[i].images;` instead of `var m = ['img_chania.jpg', 'img_chania2.jpg', 'img_flower.jpg', 'img_flower2.jpg'];`

This will throw another error further down.
`innerContent += '<div class="item' + c + '"><img src="' + m[i] + '"><div class="carousel-caption"></div>   </div>';` will not work. Instead you will have to use `m[i].href` as your source inside your image tag.

This will now pass the config to the Carousel which will then render just fine.

You might want to think about giving variables speaking names and avoiding variables like 'm'.

```
var shops = JSON.parse('{ "id": "shopping", "categories": [ { "id": "Amazon", "name": "Amazon", "link": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/SellerCentral/legal/amazon-logo_transparent._CB303899249_.png", "images": [ { "href": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/credit/img16/CBCC/marketing/marketingpage/products._V524365396_.png" }, { "href": "http://static4.uk.businessinsider.com/image/575adbe2dd0895c4098b46ba/the-50-most-popular-products-on-amazon.jpg" } ] }, { "id": "Google", "name": "Google", "link": "http://pngimg.com/uploads/google/google_PNG19644.png", "images": [ { "href": "https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/147-1476512_google-google-products-logos-png.png" }, { "href": "https://xvp.akamaized.net/assets/illustrations/unblock-google/unblock-google-with-a-vpn-fc1e32f59d9c50bae315c2c8506a91e2.png" } ] }, { "id": "Apple", "name": "Apple", "link": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Apple_Logo.svg/2000px-Apple_Logo.svg.png", "images": [ { "href": "https://c.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/apple-mfi-logos-update-2018-980x620.jpg" }, { "href": "https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/applemusic/itunes-apple-logo-apple-music-giftcard.jpg" } ] } ] }');
var row = 1;
var content = "";
shops = shops.categories;

function process() {
  for (var i = 0; i < shops.length; i++) {
    if (row == 1) {
      content += '<div class="row">'
    }
    content += '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12" data-toggle="modal" onclick="processCarousel(' + i + ')" data-target="#myModal">';
    content += '<img style="border: 1px solid red" src="' + shops[i].link + '" width="100%" height="100%"/></div>';
    if (row == 3) {
      row = 0;
      content += '</div>';
    }
    row++;
  }
  document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = content;
}

function processCarousel(i) {
  //var m = ['img_chania.jpg', 'img_chania2.jpg', 'img_flower.jpg', 'img_flower2.jpg'];
  var m = shops[i].images;
  var carouselInner = document.getElementById("carousel-inner");
  var carouselIndicators = document.getElementById("carousel-indicators");
  var innerContent = "";
  var indicatorsContent = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    var c = "";
    if (i == 0) {
      c = " active";
    }
    innerContent += '<div class="item' + c + '"><img src="' + m[i].href + '"><div class="carousel-caption"></div>   </div>';
    indicatorsContent += '<li class=' + c + 'data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="' + i + '"></li>';
  }
  carouselInner.innerHTML = innerContent;
  carouselIndicators.innerHTML = indicatorsContent;
  var carouselExampleGeneric = document.getElementById("carousel-example-generic");
  //carouselExampleGeneric.carousel();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, why we need to comment the line - `carouselExampleGeneric.carousel();`

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to do with this piece of code but I think it was throwing an error for me, so I commented it out temporarily in order to get everything else working ..